# Is it possible to create a Masonry layout for iOS and Android with Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I would like to create a Masonry (or Staggered Grid) effect with Xamarin.Forms like the following image (source of image https://masonry.desandro.com/) that works for both iOS and Android
[image]

Comment: Hey Salvo, did you find a solution?

Comment: no @Erdogan, I'm sorry

Comment: You can follow the topic; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61861777/masonry-list-style-in-xamarin

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you want to use one control like wrappanel in WPF, am I right?
If yes, I suggest you can follow these steps to do.

1.create Wraplayout class, inherit Layout in PCL.you can take a look:

https://github.com/conceptdev/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/Evolve13/Evolve13/Controls/WrapLayout.cs

2.Using this Wraplayout.

```
<xf:WrapLayout>
        <Button Text="Button A" />
        <Button Text="Button B" WidthRequest="250" />
        <Button Text="Button C" WidthRequest="150" />
        <Button Text="Button D" />
        <Button Text="Button E" WidthRequest="200" />


    </xf:WrapLayout>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but this answer is not the solution to my problem

Comment: @Salvo,According to your screenshot, do you want to use one control like wrappanel in wpf?

Comment: No, I would like to create a Masonry effect in two columns as in this link https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/pqEgBV

It is not the width of the elements that gives me problems, but their height and the "interlocking" anchor

Comment: @Salvo, II haven't found a better way to do it yet, like Masonry effect, if you have way to do this, please share here.