# Masonry list style in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms, scrollview, stacklayout

I need to list the announcements on a content page just like masonry style (https://halcyon-theme.tumblr.com/) but I couldn't be successful on it. My problem is that the Scrollview doesn't cover whole the page when I use the Parent Stacklayout's Vertical alignment option set as FillAndExpand. But if I set the Scrollview and Parent StackLayout as static height value, It's okay but due to per item's height will change, I can't use it that's the way as you guess.

> ```
>                 <StackLayout x:Name="stckParent" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
>                     <Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0">
>                         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
>                             <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
>                             <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
>                         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
>                         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
>                             <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
>                         </Grid.RowDefinitions>
>
>                         <StackLayout x:Name="stckLeft" Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,0,2,0"
>                                   Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
>                         </StackLayout>
>
>                         <StackLayout x:Name="stckRight" Grid.Column="1" Margin="2,0,0,0"
>                                   Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
>                         </StackLayout>
>
>                     </Grid>
>                 </StackLayout>
>
>             </ScrollView>
> ```

```
public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var list = new ObservableCollection<Announcement>
            {
                new Announcement
                {
                    ID = 1,
                    Title = "Yedek parça siparişlerinizde %22' ye varan indirim!",
                    ImagePath = "https://image5.sahibinden.com/photos/08/54/18/x5_719085418j7p.jpg",
                    IsActive = true,
                    CreateDate = DateTime.Now,
                },
                new Announcement
                {
                    ID = 2,
                    Title = "Fren Balataları Hangi Sıklıkla Değiştirilmelidir?",
                    ImagePath = "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTJzQfduSrJ3Nh7SHzGSGrCmTnWses4AcfuRSnU7hX4y9XN4TSU&usqp=CAU",
                    IsActive = true,
                    CreateDate = DateTime.Now,
                }
            };

            DeviceHelper helper = DependencyService.Get<IDeviceHelper>().GetDevice();

            double height = 0;

            for (int m = 0; m < 6; m++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
                {

                    Frame frame = new Frame
                    {
                        Padding = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0)
                    };

                    // Stack
                    StackLayout stack = new StackLayout
                    {
                        Margin = new Thickness(10),
                    };

                    // Image
                    Image image = new Image
                    {
                        Source = list[i].ImagePath,
                        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
                    };

                    // Title
                    Label title = new Label
                    {
                        Text = list[i].Title,
                        Margin = new Thickness(0, 6, 0, 0),
                        FontSize = 13
                    };

                    // Date
                    Label date = new Label
                    {
                        Text = list[i].CreateDate.ToString().Substring(0, 10), // temporary workaround
                        Margin = new Thickness(0, 6, 0, 0),
                        TextColor = Color.Gray,
                        FontSize = 11
                    };

                    stack.Children.Add(image);
                    stack.Children.Add(title);
                    stack.Children.Add(date);

                    frame.Content = stack;


                    if (i % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        stckLeft.Children.Add(frame);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        stckRight.Children.Add(frame);

                        SizeRequest columnSizeRequest = frame.Measure(600, 800);
                        height += columnSizeRequest.Request.Height * 6;
                    }
                }
            }
            stckLeft.HeightRequest = height;
            stckRight.HeightRequest = height;

            scrList.HeightRequest = helper.ScreenHeight - 100;

        }
```

Why Scrolview doesn't fill the whole page?
What is the best practice to able to do the masonry-style page?
How can I obtain a frame size that just bound? {

> SizeRequest columnSizeRequest = frame.Measure(300, 400); // the result
>   is always 41, It's not make sense..
>   height += columnSizeRequest.Request.Height * 6;

}

except for estimated height value, not bad :)
[image]

GitHub link;
https://github.com/Erdogan34/Test-Masonry

================= UPDATE =================

Flex-Layout;
How can I set the green box to the top?

```
<FlexLayout Direction="Row" Wrap="Wrap" AlignContent="Start"
                                JustifyContent="Start" AlignItems="Start">

                        <Frame BackgroundColor="Red" Margin="4,4">
                            <StackLayout WidthRequest="140">
                                <Label Margin="0,10" Text="Deneme"/>
                                <Label Margin="0,10" Text="Deneme"/>
                                <Label Margin="0,10" Text="Deneme"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>

                        <Frame BackgroundColor="Blue" Margin="4,4">
                             <StackLayout WidthRequest="140">
                                <Label Margin="0,10" Text="Deneme"/>
                                <Label Margin="0,10" Text="Deneme"/>
                                <Label Margin="0,10" Text="Deneme"/>
                                <Label Margin="0,10" Text="Deneme"/>
                                <Label Margin="0,10" Text="Deneme"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>

                        <Frame BackgroundColor="Green" Margin="4,4" FlexLayout.Grow="1">
                             <StackLayout WidthRequest="140">
                                <Label Margin="0,10" Text="Deneme"/>
                                <Label Margin="0,10" Text="Deneme"/>
                                <Label Margin="0,10" Text="Deneme"/>
                                <Label Margin="0,10" Text="Deneme"/>
                                <Label Margin="0,10" Text="Deneme"/>
                                <Label Margin="0,10" Text="Deneme"/>
                                <Label Margin="0,10" Text="Deneme"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>

                        <Frame BackgroundColor="Yellow" Margin="4,4" FlexLayout.Grow="1">
                             <StackLayout WidthRequest="140">
                                <Label Margin="0,10" Text="Deneme"/>
                                <Label Margin="0,10" Text="Deneme"/>
                                <Label Margin="0,10" Text="Deneme"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>

    </FlexLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: please include the relevant code in your post - do NOT just link to an external repo and expect someone to spend their valuable time reading through all of your code in order to help you

Comment: I couldn't think as you say, I've updated it. Thanks for your notice.

Comment: @Erdogan You can try to use FlexLayout to do masonry style:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/flex-layout

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT, I've updated my question, please, see the second question about Flex-Layout at the end of the question. So, how can I set the green box to the top?

Comment: @Erdogan You want to put green box to the first item? If yes, you can add `FlexLayout.Order="-1"` for green frame.

Comment: Yes, but should I calculate the size of the Green box to get it to the top? It will be a dynamic list.

Comment: I'm afraid that it is still unavailable until now . I had posted a feature request https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6554#issuecomment-614208156 and will tell you if have any update .

Comment: must read: https://checox.com/collection-masonry-style-xamarin-forms-android/?fbclid=IwAR1HZ3ipjK3BsJIlc18_3tVpdI7HdwUW2V89hFKGLwKEEYMestNDpCpAAWs

Comment: Thank you @MridulMalviya, another one;
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/175613/pinterest-app-like-collection-of-images-in-xamarin-forms